# Java - Generically handling the creation of subclasses

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

I have three classes that are quite similar, excepting a single method. Therefore, I chose to put the rest of their functionality into an abstract superclass. When it comes to creating instances of these classes, however, I'm at a loss for how to implement what seems to me like the "obvious" or "elegant" approach. Their constructors are essentially identical, and I need multiple instances of each, so I wanted to do something like the following:

```
private SubclassA[] subclassA_array, SubclassB[] subclassB_array, SubclassC[] subclassC_array;
subclassA_array = new SubclassA[getNumInstancesOfClassANeeded()]
subclassB_array = new SubclassA[getNumInstancesOfClassBNeeded()]
subclassC_array = new SubclassA[getNumInstancesOfClassCNeeded()]

// might have my syntax wrong here; array of the three subclass arrays
private Superclass[][] superArray = new Superclass[][3];
superArray[0] = subclassA_array;
superArray[1] = subclassA_array;
superArray[2] = subclassA_array;
for ( Superclass[] array: superArray )
    for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
      //  array[i] = new..... what goes here?
    }
}
```

How would I find the appropriate class to construct in that innermost loop? Is this actually a really oddball way of approaching the problem; have I missed something more obvious? Should I just say "to hell with it!" and just have three separate loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just say "to hell with it!" and just have three separate loops?

IMO, yes.

---

You could do the following:

1. Use `array.getClass()` to get the class of the array,
2. Use `getConmponentType()` to get the array's base type
3. Use `newInstance()` to create an instance
4. Assign the instance reference to the array.

... but this results in fragile code and is like using a sledge-hammer to crack a walnut.

Comment: Could you explain the "fragile" comment?

Comment: It is fragile because steps 2 and 3 involve reflective operations that potentially throw exceptions.  By contrast, with the simple approach most / all of the checking happens at compile time.  Compile time type-safety / type-checking is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with reflection in your inner loop, something like `array.getClass().getComponentType().newInstance()`, but I think there might be better solutions to the overall problem (To answer that, I'd need more information about what you want to code)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an static method

```
public static subclassA[] getNewInstances(int numberOfInstances);
```

static methods can be accessed without the need to create a new instance `SubclassA.getNewInstances(3)`.

In your definition of the matrix, you need to define first the first dimension (so it becomes `new Superclass[3][]`

Comment: I don't think I'll take that route, but it's an interesting perspective. Thanks!